# How to create a dynamic subdomain using php code?

Tags: php, web-deployment, web-hosting

I want to create subdomains using PHP code. I want to re-distribute that subdomains to my users on website. I want to know if it is possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your hosting server that they allow multiple sub domains or not.
If they allowed create an entry in subdomains for wildcard. Like:

> *.yourwebsite.com

Now write htaccess rules to pass subdomains to your php script. Like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !=yourwebsite.com
RewriteRule ^$  yourscript.php?domain=%{HTTP_HOST}  [L,QSA]
```

Now you can receive domain in your script

Comment: thank you ..how do I get to know wether hosting is allowing me to create entry in subdomains?

Comment: Which hosting provider you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You need something called wildcard subdomains in apache or nginx
If your hosting supports editing of vhosts it should be possible.

The idea is, that all folders under web root are accessed as subdomains.

Here is an example we use for nginx:

```
server {
    listen   8080;
    server_name ~^(?<webroot>[\w\-]+)\.ourdomain\.com$;

    root   /home/web/$webroot;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    set $WEB_ROOT /home/web/$webroot;
...
```

check other answers:
[nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/249952/wildcard-vhosts-on-nginx)
[apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/182929/wildcard-subdomain-directory-names)